# Synapse Apache .NET Spark (C#) parallel execution

Tags: .net, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I'm using .NET Spark in a Synapse notebook to transform data.
The source data consists of multiple parquet files within subfolders in a directory.

```
/mnt/source/f1/*.parquet
/mnt/source/f2/*.parquet
/mnt/source/f3/*.parquet
/mnt/source/.../*.parquet
```

Originally, I tried loading all parquet files in one go and transform them:

```cs
var df = spark.Read().Parquet("/source/*/*.parquet");
```

Using this, the operation would eventually timeout without any output ever generated (we're talking about roughly 50 million source records).

I can successfully transform individual folders though:

```cs
var df = spark.Read().Parquet("/source/f1/*.parquet");
```

This made me wonder if I should slice my data and iterate over the subfolders instead.

Using a simple `foreach` the job finishes in 50 minutes!

What is the correct approach to solve this? Should I use a `foreach`, a `Parallel.ForEach()` or something entirely different (Spark-specific?) to transform all input folders?

Comment: try using single `*` as folder.

Comment: @PratikLad - I just edited my post. I noticed I wasn't clear what the issue if. Using wildcard path would timeout.

Comment: If you just do a wildcard read and a count (no transformations) is it still timing out?

Comment: @ScootCork Getting counts returns after about 10 minutes with roughly 1 million rows. Note that each row has nested array data, contributing to the total of 50 million. The transformation is running joins on the nested data. (see my edits too)

Comment: Its hard to say why it is timing out, might be that your spark pool is not properly sized for the transformations you're doing, you might also have a large number of small parquet files causing long read times. You'd have to dive into what is happening (query explain plan, spark pool logs etc).